# Bringing prescription drugs into Bangkok

Tags: bangkok, drugs

I am planning to visit Thailand, Bangkok for 5 days as a tourist. However, I am also epileptic and will need the following drugs with me:

- carbamezapine
- valproic acid
- lacosamide
- risperidone

Will I be allowed to bring my drugs into the country without any problems? I wont be able to prove I have a medical condition by doctor's letter since I don't currently have a physician where I am staying.

Answer (score 1):

Thailand custom rarely checks for perscription drugs in luggage of tourists.  But if they do, as long as your pill bottles have the perscription with your name on the label, there should be no issue.

Comment: I would add that you should probably have only enough medicine to cover your stay and perhaps a two week buffer. That would make it even less likely to be other than personal use.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to have a prescription written in English. I carried a one year medication stock through south-east Asia (Laos, Vietnam and Thailand), and got no problem but the medication were available in my suitcase. Anyway you always have to check local laws.